# analysis/ode question

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that there does not exist any twice continuously differentiable function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ such that
$$
- e^{-f'} f'' + 2 f = 0.
$$

As an attempt, I drew a graph of what the solution should look like.  At zero, we know that $u(0)=u''(0)=0$ from the equation and at one, we know that $u(1)=1$ and $u''(1)= 2e^{u'(1)}>0$.  Thus, we know that there must be a point $c$ such that $u'(c)=0$ and $u(c)>0$.  But from the equation this implies that $u''(c) = 2 u(c)2e^{u'(c)}>0$.  This seems to contradict the ability of the solution to match the boundary condition at $x=0$, but I have trouble formalizing this.  Is there a simpler argument?

Comment: Try to always show some of your work so anyone trying to solve it can get a base to begin with!

Comment: thanks, I did now!

Comment: This is a significantly better question! Please do this on all your questions in the future.

Comment: Why should such point $c$ exists? Is this from some application of mean value theorem that I am not seing?

Comment: I don't know if this helps but notice that $f''$ is positive iff  $f$ is positive (since $e^{-f'}>0$)

Comment: Idle observation: Multiply with $f'$, then you can integrate $(f'+1)e^{-f'}+f^2=C$. Now analyze level curves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f^{\prime}(0)=0$, then by uniqueness, $f\equiv0$ is the unique solution.
If $f^{\prime}(0)<0$, since $f(0)=0$, we have that $f(x)<0$ for $x>0$ near
zero. But then $e^{-f^{\prime}(x)}f^{\prime\prime}(x)=2f(x)<0$ so
$f^{\prime\prime}(x)<0$, which implies that $f^{\prime}(x)<0$, so $f$ keeps
decreasing and being negative, thus, it can never happen that $f(1)=0$.

Assume next that $f^{\prime}(0)>0$. Then $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$ near $0$. In turn,
$f^{\prime\prime}(x)>0$ for $x>0$ near zero, which implies that $f^{\prime
}(x)>0$ for $x>0$ near zero. Hence, $f$ keeps increasing and staying positive,
which in turn implies that $f^{\prime\prime}>0$. This shows that $f>0$ in
$(0,1]$ and $f^{\prime}>0$ in $[0,1]$.

Next, multiply $e^{-f^{\prime}(x)}f^{\prime\prime}(x)=2f(x)$ by $f^{\prime
}(x)$ and integrate to get
$$
\int_{0}^{x}f^{\prime}(s)e^{-f^{\prime}(s)}f^{\prime\prime}(s)\,ds=\int%
_{0}^{x}2f(s)f^{\prime}(s)\,dx=f^{2}(x).
$$
Making the change of variables $y=f^{\prime}(s)$ we get
$$
\int_{f^{\prime}(0)}^{f^{\prime}(x)}te^{-t}dt=f^{2}(x),
$$
that is,
$$
-e^{-f^{\prime}(x)}(f^{\prime}(x)+1)+e^{-f^{\prime}(0)}(f^{\prime}
(0)+1)=f^{2}(x),
$$
or, equivalently
$$
e^{f^{\prime}(0)}(f^{\prime}(0)+1)=e^{f^{\prime}(x)}(f^{\prime}(x)+1)+f^{2}
(x).
$$
Consider the function $g(t)=e^{-t}\left(  t+1\right)  $. We have $g(0)=1$ and
$g^{\prime}(t)=-te^{-t}<0$ for $t>0$. Hence, $g(t)<1$ for all $t>0$. In
particular, $g(f^{\prime}(0))<1$, which implies that
$$
1>e^{f^{\prime}(0)}(f^{\prime}(0)+1)=e^{f^{\prime}(x)}(f^{\prime}
(x)+1)+f^{2}(x)
$$
for all $x>0$. Taking $x=1$, we get a contradiction, since $f^{\prime}(1)>0$.